# jQuery on click main menu item, if has child toggle sub menu, else open link

Tags: jquery, menu, contains, items

I am trying to create a menu with sub items. All is well except the main items that don't have any sub items should open their own links.

Right now the toggle works like it should but when I click the main items without any sub items, they don't do anything..

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="menu-primary" style="display: block;">
        <ul class="v-list" id="menu-menu-1">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-23" id="menu-item-23"><a href="somepath.php">Browse by Type</a></li>

            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-30" id="menu-item-30">
                <a>aaaa</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21" id="menu-item-21"><a href="somepath.php">Browse by Author</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22" id="menu-item-22"><a href="somepath.php">Browse by Country</a></li>

            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20" id="menu-item-20"><a href="somepath.php">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
$('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
    if($(this).closest("li.menu-item").children("ul.sub-menu").length)
        {
            $('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
        }
        else {
            var url = $(this).closest("li.menu-item").attr('href');
            window.open(url);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DcG5R/ works..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the `return: false;` should do it, and then rely on the default behaviour of the anchor to proceed and change the `target` on the anchor. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6xU5/)

```
$('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
    if($(this).closest("li.menu-item").children("ul.sub-menu").length > 0)
    {
        $('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    }            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

First, your selector `$('.menu-item')` already selects the `<li>` elements, so calling `$(this).closest('li.menu-item')` is redundant; `$(this)` matches the exact same element - you can remove all of those calls to `.closest()` from your code.

Second, the `href` attribute is on the `<a>` element, not the `<li>` element that you're currently trying to get it from. Change that line to:

```
var url = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I improved the code and it works now, thank you :)